# EXECUTE fail does not proceed next

Tags: postgresql

I have created a function remove_tables which is as shown below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_tables (integer)
    RETURNS void AS
$BODY$DECLARE    
    _id ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE something_' || _id || ' CASCADE';
    DELETE FROM lot WHERE id = _id ;
END;$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION delete_tables(integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

My problem is, EXECUTE may failed but i still want to proceed with DELETE statement (DELETE FROM lot WHERE id = _id ;)

I try use PERFORM 'DROP TABLE something_' || _id || ' CASCADE'; but does not give what i want

Is there anything i can do to EXECUTE one statement regardless of success or failure, and still proceed with other statement

Comment: You need an exception handler: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING (you will also need to set a savepoint so that you continue with the transaction in case of an error)

Comment: ok thanks, i have tried to catch the exception and do nothing, looks ok for what i need

Comment: If you all you want is to prevent an error if the table does not exist, use `drop table if exist ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put exception handling around the block you expect to fail.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_tables (integer)
    RETURNS void AS
$BODY$DECLARE    
    _id ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE something_' || _id || ' CASCADE';
    EXCEPTION WHEN read_only_sql_transaction THEN
    -- Do nothing
    END;
    DELETE FROM lot WHERE id = _id ;
END;$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION delete_tables(integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

See the documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html (40.6.6. Trapping Errors).

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/errcodes-appendix.html for exception codes.

Comment: ok thanks, thats what @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out above, thanks for the answer :) By the way, is there any performance issue with exception trap?

Comment: Yeah, just thought that adding a more complete answer will help anyone looking for a solution a similar problem in the future. I am not aware of any performance issue but if you're dropping tables often you may add a check first to make sure the table exists and can be dropped.

Comment: thanks :) I have check table exists and it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the exception trap pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name and @Onots, using exception trap working good

I also tried the other method mentioned by @Onots to check table exists or not, also working good

due to i am not sure about trapping exception will have any impact on performance, I have used the code which check for table exists before dropping it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_tables (integer)
    RETURNS void AS
$BODY$DECLARE    
    _id ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = something_' || _id) THEN
        EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE something_' || _id || ' CASCADE';
    ENDIF;
    DELETE FROM lot WHERE id = _id ;
END;$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION delete_tables(integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Why not simply use `drop table if exists ...` instead?

Comment: ok thanks you give me a better way, i use to check for table exists before execute some other statement :) anyway thanks for pointing out this